# How do you remove stick-on hooks?

Tags: adhesive

I'm not sure of the name but you know those hooks that come with an adhesive strip that attaches to a wall and you put the hook over it? The hook part broke off but the adhesive strip and the plastic part that touches it is still on the door. How do you remove it? I tried pulling it with pliers but the little bit of plastic the pliers was gripping broke off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had success sawing through them with dental floss. Get an 18" piece of floss. wrap each end around your fingers or a pencil. Slide the floss behind the plastic section. while applying a downward pressure on the floss, move it back and forth left to right until the hook separates from the adhesive. Once you have access to the adhesive you can scrape it off or use an adhesive remover like GooGone, rubbing alcohol or citrus based cleaner.

Comment: A popular Water Displacing penetrating oil also works well for dissolving the remaining adhesive goo. It has at least 40 other uses as well.

Comment: The floss worked! I really had to slide it side to side, if I just pulled down it wouldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Tried this but floss kept breaking. Anyone tried doing this after heating up hook and adhesive with blowdryer?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed two cable clips with self-adhesive pads recently.  They were stuck on solid however reading these answers where alcohols were identified as a solvent for the adhesive, I used a 1ml hypodermic syringe to inject acetone into the pads (going in through the edge in a couple of places).  Both clips fell off in seconds.  If the adhesive pads are similar on your hooks, there's good chance this will work.

[image: Clips after removal with acetone injection]

Answer (score 0):

All of the ones that I've ever bought had instructions on the package, and it was essentially this:

1. Remove the hook by pushing it upwards off of the mounting base.
2. Hold the mounting base gently, but don't press it against the wall, and grab the tab at the bottom end of the foam strip, which is not stuck to the wall.
3. Pull the tab straight downwards, **slowly**. The foam strip will stretch and come off of the wall cleanly.

If your hook doesn't have a mounting base, then the tab should be visible and accessible without removing the hook. See various product-specific instructions [here](https://command.3m.co.uk/3M/en_GB/command-gb/hooks-strips/).

***Emphasis on slowly! Sticky tape will stretch and stretch to 6" long, then the base will fall of and there will be no residue on the glass or wall.***

Comment: Original post said the hook had broken off. As has mine, so pushing on the hook won’t work

Comment: @tomh If the hook has broken off, doesn't that just mean you can skip step 1?